# What would be the best way or methodology to find my users' web browser?

Tags: user-research, research, user-centered-design, browser, webforms

I'm designing a new web project for a company. For the success this project, it will be very important to know the main web browsers that users use. What do you think would be the best research methodology for this? It will be effective if I launch a research form for them? I have the impression that they are not smart to answer this questions very well, because most people won't know the browser version.

So, are there any other ways to get this information other than using a form?

Comment: Why is it very important to know the specific browsers?

Comment: Ask them. Ask the user! You don't need a research methodology. Just reach out to your user base and *ask them*!

Comment: @DA01 - one thought (perhaps not true to the OP), is browser support. I've used IE usage statistics in the past to argue the need for support, but mostly I use those statistics to argue the need to update. :)

Comment: It's really important. This is something most of us gives for granted, but just to give an example, we're having lots of issues with an app with some features not working on IE8. Yes, an outdated and unsupported browser.... Installed in many corporate computers in US. The target for our app is... executives working with those computers. So yes, it's of foremost importance (and I'm not even considering mobile browsers vs desktop browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, calling your users stupid probably isn't the best way to begin the research. Second, most people with any experience in this industry will know it's extremely easy to pull that info from an analytics report or a simple bit of JavaScript code.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So, Can I put a JavaScript code on my form to get this like a Google Form?  tks.

Comment: Yes, this data will be in the existing analytics (web logs). But note that that can lead to bad assumptions as well. For instance, if you have parts of your site that simply don't work with some browsers (which was common back in the day), people with other browsers wouldn't show up in your logs because they'd give up on your site...but those other browsers were absolutely customers you want to target. So just be wary of analytics on this level. It's useful information, but don't treat it as gospel.

Comment: Nothing you do will get you exact numbers. A basic analytics report will get you going in the right direction. Want to know if more people are using IE or Chrome? Just look at the logs and you'll get a good idea.

Comment: @PedroLalli There are a few ways to go about it. It all depends on your setup. Backend code, front end code, server logs, Google Analytics...

Comment: @PaulDessert right, but my point is that if your existing site doesn't *work* with Chrome, then a lack of Chrome browsers in your logs isn't necessarily indicative of what your users *want* to use. Admittedly, this is less of an issue today than 10 years ago when browser-centric sites were being built. But given the OP is even asking this question, I worry that they *do* have a site that currently is only targetting particular browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the User-Agent property of the HTTP Request Header

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43

Comment: I wanted to also comment that a good technique if you are worried about a particular feature being compatible with the browser is to write a JavaScript function to detect if the function is available and then a fall back if it is not.  JS 
`<script type="text/javascript"> 
            if(window.addEventListener)
            { 
                 window.addEventListener("load", myFunction, false);
            } 
            else if(window.attachEvent)
           { 
                 window.attachEvent("onload", myFunction);
           }</script>`